# Circle Geometry and Conic Section textbook

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

I seek a textbook for good conic section and circle geometry questions. Slightly above introductory level. - slightly. But I wouldn't mind introductory level questions to consolidate my knowledge.

I am semi-comfortable with the two topics, I just need more questions to get me through the winter nights. Any suggestions?

Nothing too over the top, I am still a first year student!

Comment: First year of high school or first year of college?

Comment: First year/high school is fine. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

"Geometry of conics" by Akopyan and Zaslavskiĭ is the closest thing to what you are looking for. The book's first half is what you would be interested in, later on it delves into the projective geometry. You can obtain the pdf for this book freely just by searching for the name.